# System of equations. Displaying following equations in a bracket and automatically printing results attached to the variables (in R-markdown)

Tags: r

With your help i made this program solving the system of linear equations from a string using Gauss-Jordan method.

```
my_string<-"2a+5b-2c+2d=9; 3a-2b+1c-3d=34; -3a+3b+2c+4d=33; 2a+3b+4c+5d=125"

sp1 <- unlist(strsplit(my_string, ";"))
sp1
sp2 <- strsplit(sp1, "=")
sp2
b <- as.numeric(sapply(sp2, '[[', 2))
b

sp3 <- lapply(lapply(sp2, '[[', 1), function(s) gsub("([-+])([[:alpha:]])", "\\11\\2", s))
sp3

sp3 <- lapply(sp3, trimws)
sp3

sp3 <- lapply(sp3, function(s1) sub("^([[:alpha:]])", "1\\1", s1))
sp3

A <- do.call(rbind, lapply(sp3, function(x) as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x,"[[:alpha:]]")))))
A

p <- nrow(A)
(U.pls <- cbind(A,b))


U.pls[1,] <- U.pls[1,]/U.pls[1,1] 
U.pls
i <- 2
while (i < p+1) {
  j <- i
  while (j < p+1) {
    U.pls[j, ] <- U.pls[j, ] - U.pls[i-1, ] * U.pls[j, i-1]
    j <- j+1
    print(U.pls)
    }
  while (U.pls[i,i] == 0) {
    U.pls <- rbind(U.pls[-i,],U.pls[i,])
    print(U.pls)
  }
  U.pls[i,] <- U.pls[i,]/U.pls[i,i]
  i <- i+1
  print(U.pls)
}

for (i in p:2){
  for (j in i:2-1) {
    U.pls[j, ] <- U.pls[j, ] - U.pls[i, ] * U.pls[j, i]
    U.pls[j, ] - U.pls[i, ] * U.pls[j, i]
   print(U.pls) 
  }
}
U.pls[,p+1]
```

I have two questions. First. Is it possible in R to display this system (somewhere at the beginning of this program) like this (every column should stand for a different variable):

```
 2a + 5b - 2c + 2d = 9 
 3a - 2b + 1c - 3d = 34 
-3a + 3b + 2c + 4d = 33 
 2a + 3b + 4c + 5d = 125
```

but in a bracket? How to do this?

The second question is how to automatically print the results (values of the variables). Now my output looks like this:

```
[1] 10  5 20  2
```

but I want to gain this:

```
a=10, b=5, c=20, d=2
```

I would be really thankful for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a function which does all of your work and adds a version of your requested output.

The first answer is not as clean as you requested, but I hope this leads you in the right direction.

```
    your_requested_output<-function() {
      answer<-vector()
      my_string<-"2x+5y-2z+2p=9; 3x-2y+1z-3p=34; -3x+3y+2z+4p=33; 2x+3y+4z+5p=125"
sp1 <- unlist(strsplit(my_string, ";"))
sp1
sp2 <- strsplit(sp1, "=")
sp2
      my_string<-gsub("x","a",my_string)
      my_string<-gsub("y","b",my_string)
      my_string<-gsub("z","c",my_string)
      my_string<-gsub("p","d",my_string)
      my_string<-strsplit(my_string, ";")
      my_string<-unlist(my_string)
      my_string<-trimws(my_string)
      for (i in 1:4) {
        print(paste0(my_string[i]))
      }
      b <- as.numeric(sapply(sp2, '[[', 2))
      sp3 <- lapply(lapply(sp2, '[[', 1), function(s) gsub("([-+])([[:alpha:]])", "\\11\\2", s))
      sp3 <- lapply(sp3, trimws)
      sp3 <- lapply(sp3, function(s1) sub("^([[:alpha:]])", "1\\1", s1))
      A <- do.call(rbind, lapply(sp3, function(x) as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x,"[[:alpha:]]")))))
      p <- nrow(A)
      (U.pls <- cbind(A,b))
      U.pls[1,] <- U.pls[1,]/U.pls[1,1]
      i <- 2
      while (i < p+1) {
        j <- i
        while (j < p+1) {
          U.pls[j, ] <- U.pls[j, ] - U.pls[i-1, ] * U.pls[j, i-1]
          j <- j+1
        }
      while (U.pls[i,i] == 0) {
        U.pls <- rbind(U.pls[-i,],U.pls[i,])
      }
      U.pls[i,] <- U.pls[i,]/U.pls[i,i]
      i <- i+1
    }

    for (i in p:2){
      for (j in i:2-1) {
        U.pls[j, ] <- U.pls[j, ] - U.pls[i, ] * U.pls[j, i]
        U.pls[j, ] - U.pls[i, ] * U.pls[j, i]
      }
    }
    answer<-c(answer, paste0(letters[1:4],"=",U.pls[,p+1]))
    return(answer)
    }
    your_requested_output()
```